# Create a factory class that returns an empty-struct implementation

Tags: memory, struct, rust, heap-memory

I'd like to create a common interface for formatters, that will take the input and format it according to their purpose.

Currently I'm returning a Box containing the formatter implementation (wrapped into a Result). But I don't think this is the best way to do it. Since the Formatter implementations are empty structs, allocating heap memory for a Box doesn't make sense.

```
pub trait Formatter {
    fn format_information(&self, information: Result<Information, Error>) -> Result<String, Error>;
    fn format_information_collection(&self, information: InformationCollection) -> Result<String, Error>;
}

pub struct JsonFormatter;
impl Formatter for JsonFormatter {...}

pub struct XmlFormatter;
impl Formatter for XmlFormatter {...}


// Factory to create a formatter
pub struct Factory;
impl Factory {
    pub fn get_formatter(format: &str) -> Result<Box<Formatter>, Error> {
        match format {
            "json" => Ok(Box::new(JsonFormatter {})),
            "xml" => Ok(Box::new(XmlFormatter {})),
            _ => Err(Error::new(format!("No formatter found for format {}", format)))
        }
    }
}

// Use the factory
let formatter_box = Factory::get_formatter(format).unwrap();
let formatter = &*formatter_box as &Formatter;
```

What's the correct way to do this in Rust?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Since the Formatter implementations are empty structs, allocating heap memory for a `Box` doesn't make sense.

And since it doesn't make any sense, heap memory won't be allocated at all. Let's try it ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=45f7ae4c87125f826779293b0f23a667&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
// `()` doesn't occupy any space, like e.g. your `JsonFormatter`
let b1 = Box::new(());
let b2 = Box::new(());

println!("{:p}\n{:p}", &*b1, &*b2);
```

This produces the output:

```
0x1
0x1
```

ZSTs (zero sized types) are often treated in a special way. So at least you know you aren't paying for heap allocations here. Note however, that the memory layout of your `Box<Formatter>` is a fat pointer and looks like this: `(*mut Formatter, *mut VTable)`. The first pointer always being `0x1`, the second one pointing to a statically allocated dispatch table which contains function pointer ([vtable - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)). This is probably fine in your situation.

---

Another possibility is to create an enum like this:

```
enum FormatterSd {
    Json(JsonFormatter),
    Xml(XmlFormatter),
}
```

And now you can implement `Formatter for FormatterSd`; in this implementation you will use simple `match` blocks to do dispatch. That way you don't need to use `Box`.

---

Lastly: you don't need to have a factory type! It seems a bit like you are trying to bring ideas from a strongly OO programming language into Rust. Often, this is not the best or most idiomatic solution. For example, there are free functions in Rust. So you can simply write:

```
fn get_formatter(format: &str) -> Result<Box<Formatter>, Error> {
    // ...
}
```

Yes, without the `Factory` type! Empty types are a lot less common in Rust than empty classes (meaning: without any fields). You can just use free function for this kind of stuff, there is no need to associate it with a type.

And lastly lastly: you don't need to manually obtain a reference from a `Box`:

```
let formatter = &*formatter_box as &Formatter;
```

You can simple say `formatter_box.format_information(...);`, thanks to deref coercions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I learned a lot. I'm starting with Rust and my workday language is PHP :)